# HTLC implementation manually

Tags: node.js, bitcoin, lightning-network

Is there any way to implement HTLC manually for locking funds in the channels in lightning network and releasing the funds after the time lock expired.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to ask that question on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com however if you look at the lightning network specification (aka BOLT) at [BOLT 03 transactions](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/03-transactions.md#offered-htlc-outputs) you will for example find this script for a commitment transaction

```
# To remote node with revocation key
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(SHA256(revocationpubkey))> OP_EQUAL
OP_IF
    OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ELSE
    <remote_htlcpubkey> OP_SWAP OP_SIZE 32 OP_EQUAL
    OP_NOTIF
        # To local node via HTLC-timeout transaction (timelocked).
        OP_DROP 2 OP_SWAP <local_htlcpubkey> 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
    OP_ELSE
        # To remote node with preimage.
        OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(payment_hash)> OP_EQUALVERIFY
        OP_CHECKSIG
    OP_ENDIF
OP_ENDIF
```

Also note that there is a [standalone BIP 199  which is still a draft but specifies how to work with htlcs](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0199.mediawiki).

Comment: Any idea on how to use these scripts?

Comment: Yeah you put them in a Bitcoin transaction where they are executed when the blocks are validated.